# What is the type of "sys.version_info"?

Tags: python, python-typing

How would I add type annotations to the following function?

```py
import sys

def f(info):
    return info.major

f(sys.version_info)
```

Using `pyannotate` suggests that it should be:

```py
import sys

def f(info):
    # type: (sys.version_info) -> int
    return info.major

f(sys.version_info)
```

However `mypy` complains:

````
$ mypy test.py
test.py:10: error: Variable "sys.version_info" is not valid as a type
test.py:12: error: sys.version_info? has no attribute "major"```
````

The type of `sys.version_info` seems to be itself:

```
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys.version_info)
<class 'sys.version_info'>
```

It looks like a `NamedTuple`, but if it's annotated as such:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

VersionInfo = NamedTuple(
    'sys.version_info', [
        ('major', int),
        ('minor', int),
        ('micro', int),
        ('releaselevel', str),
        ('serial', int)
    ]
)

import sys

def f(info):
    # type: (VersionInfo) -> int
    return info.major

f(sys.version_info)
```

The `mypy` check still fails:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "_version_info"; expected "sys.version_info@9"
```

Comment: I would consider this one of the cases where it's best to just not insist on annotating everything. Not every part of Python plays well with type annotations.

Comment: It is a `NamedTuple`, but annotating it as `NamedTuple` still doesn't solve the problem about accessing `major`...

Comment: @Sraw It's not a `NamedTuple`, see my edit.

Comment: `help(sys.version_info)` says it's descended from `builtins.tuple` and in the prose description it says "Version information as a named tuple".  I guess these should be reconciled and perhaps a bug raised against MyPY,.

Comment: looks like it should be a namedtuple https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/41c57b335330ff48af098d47e379e0f9ba09d233/Python/sysmodule.c#L2308

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to find what the type of some standard library function, you should look at [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), the repository of type hints for the standard library + select 3rd party modules.

In this case, we can see that `sys.version_info` is [annotated as being of type `sys._version_info`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/sys.pyi#L122), which is a fake, synthesized type-only class that subclasses `Tuple[int, int, int, str, int]`.

You can verify this for yourself by also running mypy against the following program:

```
import sys
reveal_type(sys.version_info)
```

This results in the following output -- note the fallback at the very end:

```
 Revealed type is 'Tuple[builtins.int, builtins.int, builtins.int, builtins.str, builtins.int, fallback=sys._version_info]'
```

---

So, to annotate your function, you have several options. First, you could use this type-check-only class -- you just need to make sure you never import it/reference it at runtime.

If you're using the type comment syntax (e.g. `# type: (sys._version_info) -> int`), this problem is already solved for you. After all, snippets of code in comments are never evaluated at runtime.

But if you want to use Python-3 style type annotations, you could do:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import sys

def f(info: sys._version_info) -> int:
    return info.major

f(sys.version_info)
```

The `__future__` import basically makes the above program equivalent to the below -- all type hints are treated as strings, and so won't need to be evaluated at runtime:

```py
import sys

def f(info: "sys._version_info") -> int:
    return info.major

f(sys.version_info)
```

Alternatively, you could also do this, if you want to explicitly import the type without the `sys` module namespace:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
import sys

# Doing just 'if False:' also works
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from sys import _version_info as VersionInfo

def f(info: VersionInfo) -> int:
    return info.major

f(sys.version_info)
```